# Yii2 restful - cannot use the costom action in the ActiveController

Tags: php, rest, yii2

I am new on Yii2 and I'm trying to build a restful API.

I need create few custom actions for getting data.

When I call https://localhost/api/v1/record/GetAll using GET method, which will return 404.

Here is the log

```
[yii\web\HttpException:404] yii\base\InvalidRouteException: Unable to resolve the request: v1/record/getall in /home/demo/vendor/yiisoft/yii2/base/Controller.php:149
Stack trace:
#0 /home/demo/vendor/yiisoft/yii2/base/Module.php(552): yii\base\Controller->runAction()
#1 /home/demo/vendor/yiisoft/yii2/web/Application.php(103): yii\base\Module->runAction()
#2 /home/demo/vendor/yiisoft/yii2/base/Application.php(384): yii\web\Application->handleRequest()
#3 /home/demo/api/web/index.php(18): yii\base\Application->run()
#4 {main}

Next yii\web\NotFoundHttpException: Page not found. in /home/demo/vendor/yiisoft/yii2/web/Application.php:115
Stack trace:
#0 /home/demo/vendor/yiisoft/yii2/base/Application.php(384): yii\web\Application->handleRequest()
#1 /home/demo/api/web/index.php(18): yii\base\Application->run()
#2 {main}
```

Here is the project directory structure

```
api
-config
--main.php
-modules
--v1
---controllers
----RecordController.php
---Module.php
-runtime
-web
frontend
backend
common
...
```

Here is my code

**api\config\main.php**

```
...
'urlManager' => [
            'class'=>'yii\web\UrlManager',
            'enablePrettyUrl' => true,
            'enableStrictParsing' => true,
            'showScriptName' => false,
            'rules' => [
                [
                    'class' => 'yii\rest\UrlRule', 
                    'controller' => ['v1/record'=>'v1/record'],
                    //'prefix' => 'record/<id:\\w+>',
                    'pluralize' => false,
                    
                    'extraPatterns' => [
                        'GET,HEAD getAll'=>'getall',
                        'OPTIONS getAll'=>'options',
                    ],
                    
                ],
            ],        
        ],
...
```

**api\modules\v1\controllers\RecordController.php**

```
namespace api\modules\v1\controllers;

use yii\rest\ActiveController;
use common\components\JsonSerializer;
use yii\filters\ContentNegotiator;
use yii\web\Response;
use yii\web\ForbiddenHttpException;
use frontend\models\Record;
class RecordController extends ActiveController
{
    public $modelClass = 'frontend\models\Record';
    public $serializer = [
        'class' => 'common\components\JsonSerializer',
        'collectionEnvelope' => 'items',
    ];
    protected function verbs(){
        return [
            'getAll' => [ 'GET' ],
        ];
        //return $verbs;
    }
    
    public function actions()
    {
        $actions = parent::actions();
        
        
        $actions['options'] = [
        'class' => 'yii\rest\OptionsAction',
        ];
        return $actions;

    }

//the custom action - getAll
    public function actiongetAll(){
        $result = Record::find()
        ->all();
        
        return $result;
    }
}
```

The default actions[index,view,update,create,delete] are OK, but the custom action cannot get the data.

How can I fix it.

Thanks.

Comment: You should start by following naming conventions for action methods/IDs. The method name should be `actionGetAll` instead of `actiongetAll` and you should use `get-all` in verbs/route and not `GetAll` or `getAll`. See https://www.yiiframework.com/doc/guide/2.0/en/structure-controllers#inline-actions for more info.

Comment: @Michal Hynčica OMG, it works... you're my hero!

Answer (score 0):

First I would change the action function in your controller to

`public function actionGetAll()`

Then your URL will be https://localhost/api/v1/record/get-all

and please use this `get-all` in your rules and verbs.

If you override the url-rule I think you have to use this

`'GET,HEAD getAll'=>'v1/record/get-all',`